# How to disable host name verification in Quarkus app for SSL connection?

Tags: java, ssl, quarkus

I know, i can disable host name verification when directly using `HttpsUrlConnection` with `connection.setHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid)`.

But, what options i have using Quarkus framework (which incapsulates connection code) to avoid exceptions like this:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No name matching some-host.com found
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Where is you application code and entry point? How are you running it? In which mode? Is it a native image? Please provide as much context as possible and not a single line exception.

Comment: "I know, i can disable host name verification" You shouldn't do that. Whatever the problem is, removing hostname verification is not the solution. It means you loose the core feature of TLS and basically go back to pure plain text messages...

Comment: Are you using the REST client from Microprofile?